# List view button in Lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, list-view, list-button

*I know this is not a new thing but wanted to put some more focus on it to get working solution*

**I need to create a "List View Button" using *pure Lighting* (No VF Page at all). 
Till now I have tried few approaches but it has some setbacks.**

> **Approach 1** : List view Button with URL using `lightning:isUrlAddressable`/ Lighting Tab

- This One I found good to use but its considerably slow. Even the most basic Component takes time to load.
- If you revisit this button 2nd time(without getting page reloaded), method `<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>` won't be triggered.

> **Approach 2** : [Lighting Mass Quick Actions](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mass_quick_actions_create.htm&type=5)

- While setting this up, I am getting stuck at #5 in above link.
- My Quick Action is not showing up for selection even after creating multiple Quick actions. The ones without LC are also now showing up for selection. As per snap below.

[image]

---

> **Code Snippet:**

**Component:**

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,lightning:isUrlAddressable,force:lightningQuickAction,force:appHostable" controller="ControllerName" access="public" >
    <lightning:navigation aura:id="navService"/>
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
    <aura:attribute name="isModalOpen" type="Boolean" default="false"/>    
    <aura:attribute name="modelStatus" type="Map"/>
</aura:component>
```

**Controller :**

```
({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {

        /* SOME BUSINESS LOGIC TO CONDITIONALLY REDIRECT */

        var pageReference = {
            type: 'standard__objectPage',
            attributes: {
                objectApiName: 'Account',
                actionName: 'list'
            },
            state: {
                filterName: "All"
            }
        };

        var navService = component.find("navService");
        navService.navigate(pageReference);
    }

})
```